# Time running out of sync on a CentOS 7 server

Tags: linux, centos, time, ntp

i have a problem with one of our webservers running on a CentOS 7. The local and UTC time on the system has been changing for about the last 1 to 2 weeks regularly by several minutes and hours. The RTC time remains in time.

I was able to observe the phenomenon directly in a SSH seassion. Here the time changed within approx. 5 minutes by 51 seconds.

```
[root@*** ~]# ntpdate 0.de.pool.ntp.org
31 Jul 14:26:07 ntpdate[9738]: step time server 80.153.195.191 offset 156.552788 sec
[root@*** ~]# date
Wed Jul 31 14:26:23 CEST 2019
[root@*** ~]# date
Wed Jul 31 14:28:05 CEST 2019
[root@*** ~]# date
Wed Jul 31 14:31:18 CEST 2019
[root@*** ~]# date
Wed Jul 31 14:31:27 CEST 2019
[root@*** ~]# date
Wed Jul 31 14:31:37 CEST 2019
[root@*** ~]# ntpdate 0.de.pool.ntp.org
31 Jul 14:32:51 ntpdate[11898]: step time server 134.34.3.18 offset 51.911962 sec
```

What have I already tried (unsuccessfully):

- i changed the ntpd config and tried different time servers to adjust it
- i have activated the ntpd statistics (here an excerpt where the problem appears at the end [example](https://pastebin.com/SdCEwNB7))
- i have completely deactivated ntpd
- I have reset the time by hand and by ntpdate
- I have reset the time zone
- i asked the hoster if there is any hardware problem on the master system

I hope you have more ideas where I can look or what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Is this a virtual server or physical?

Comment: @uprego it is a virtual server with dedicated storage. This is also the reason why i contacted the provider to ask if there was any problem with the parent system. That was denied.

Comment: Is NTP server even running? Can you post the output of `systemctl status` for the NTP daemon you're using?

Comment: @filbranden at the moment its not running cause i stopped it to check if its part of the problem

Comment: Fork some disposable linked clones and compare jittering.